# Android WebView With Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: javascript, php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently have an Android application that loads my website inside a WebView.

```
WebView browserView;
browserView.loadUrl(URL);
```

I have also implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging so I can utilize push notifications.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Send the token to the server
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL + "/API.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("action=insertDeviceID&deviceID=" + refreshedToken);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            is.close();
            rd.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

When `sendRegistrationToServer()` is run my API populates a table with the ID of the current Android device. Here is a picture:

[image]

The problem is that I have no way of getting the `user_id` until the person has logged in to the website via the Android WebView. As you can probably guess, this means I do not know which device is associated with which user. This is a problem for sending push notifications to certain users.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

**Note**: I have already debated making a native Android application and do not want to do that. I also have thought of simply loading the website in a native web browser like Chrome or Firefox, however, I also do not want to do that.

**Thoughts**: Could it be possible to "trigger" a function in the Android application when a user logs in on the website and pass the `user_id`?

**More thoughts**: Can I accomplish this using WebView's `addJavascriptInterface()`?

Comment: You're (obviously) going to have to find a way to send the token to the server only after the user has logged in and you have their UID.  This is probably going to be more complicated than could be explored here on SO.  If your app is essentially a web app hosted in an Android shell, you're right in that you're going to have to bridge between the JavaScript in your web part to your Java in the Android part.

Comment: Is it really complicated? It sounds like I could send the device id when the app is installed, then when a user logs in call a Java function in the Android app via JS in the web app, then the Java function calls the API again and posts the device ID. Then the API would grab the UID from the PHP session and update the row where the device ID matches. Is this complicated?

Comment: Give it a shot and answer your own question if you figure it out. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using my solution in the comments. I used the function `addJavascriptInterface()` which is part of the Android WebView class. By using it I was able to call back to my Android application after I log in to the website. I then call my API and pass the user id and device id.

Comment: Please can u send me ur link i'm working on same soultion